# How to remove specificly the last <p></p> tag in all posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, posts, paragraph

I want to remove the last paragraph of content in all of my posts, which always have a

tag on their own.

```
example: <p>content I want to keep</p> 
         <p>content I want to remove<p/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with Regex:

```
preg_grep('/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/', explode('\n', $input_lines));
```

that will return an array with every line of `<p>...</p>`. Unset the last key of that array and then keep working with it.